# How to write in a binary file without removing its contents ? (JAVA)

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

I want to create a bank questions application in java using a binary file to store the questions. I faced a problem which is removing the binary file contents when writing in it again. How could I solve this problem easily?

```java
import java.io.*;

import java.util.ArrayList; public class Maiun {​​​​

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {​​​​

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("BinaryFile.dat"));

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("BinaryFile.dat"));

        ArrayList<String> ques = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for (int i = 1; i < 11 ; i++){
            ​​​​output.writeUTF(i + " Hello\n");
            ques.add(i + " hello");

        }​​​​

        for(int i = 0 ; i < ques.size() ; i++) {​​​​

            System.out.print(input.readUTF());         }​​​​             

    }​​​​ }​​​​
```

The expected output is when I run the code twice, the first contents will not be deleted

Comment: can you please post what have you tried till now. This will help others to guide you . Also if possible plz post the actual output you got and what was the expected outcome.

Comment: @Knowledge_seeker Done

Comment: Not done!!!   You haven't explained what the expected output is; i.e. precisely what you want the file to look like after you have written to it.

Comment: The answer is I think that you need to open the output file in append mode; see the FileOutputStream javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //create a path to that file
    Path binaryFile = Path.of("BinaryFile.dat");
    
    try {
        
        //If the file doesn't exist create new one (StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
       Files.writeString(binaryFile,"Text here",StandardCharsets.UTF_8,StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
       
      // check the content file, the Files.lines(Path path) returns a Stream<String> with all lines.
       Files.lines(binaryFile).forEach(System.out::println);
       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```